# An issue with an unknown rule in Tailwind CSS

Tags: html, css, frontend, tailwind-css

- When I try to put the directives in my CSS, I get an this problem "Unknown at rule @tailwind css(unknonwAtRules)", however, I'm using the latest version v3.3.3, and I put those directives: @tailwind base; @tailwind components; @tailwind utilities;
- When I tried to use "text-color" nothing changed to the HTML file
- please can anybody help me, I'm a beginner in Tailwindcss. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Tailwind to add the text color add `color-red` format not text-color

Comment: i added <body class="text-red-700">